# How to add new elements for a key in a mutable.Map?

Tags: scala, dictionary

I want to continuously add values to `Keys` in a `mutable.Map` in Scala. The values of each Key is as Type of `Tuple2[Double,Int]`.
I use the below code to define a `mutable.Map`:

```
val my_var: mutable.Map[Int, (Double, Int)] = new mutable.HashMap[Int, (Double, Int)]
```

I use below code to add new values:

```
my_var += (1 -> (2.5, 3))
my_var += (1 -> (4.5, 1))
my_var += (2 -> (1.5, 1))
```

But for example, for `key=1` only the last values is stored. But I want to store all the values assigned to the specific key. The final result that I want look likes this:

```
(1,((2.5,3),(4.5,1),...))
...
```

Comment: A **Map** only has one value for a key. If you want multiple values you need a `Map[Int,List[(Double, Int)]]` and you would need to implement the logic of appending elements to the list for the same key.

Comment: Sorry i ask, but i am having some confusion with these operations, Can i ask you to help me with the code so i can accept it for my problem?

Comment: Something like `map.updatedWith(key) { case Some(list) => Some(list :+ value); case None => Some(List(value)) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want mutability all the way, I would use `mutable.Map` with `ListBuffer` there:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val map = mutable.Map.empty[Int, mutable.ListBuffer[(Double, Int)]]

implicit class AppendOps[K, V](private val map: mutable.Map[K, mutable.ListBuffer[V]]) {
  def append(key: K, value: V) = {
    map.updateWith(key) {
      case Some(list) => Some(list.append(value))
      case None       => Some(mutable.ListBuffer(value))
    }
  }
}

map.append(1, (2.5,3))
map.append(1, (4.5,1))
map.append(2, (1.5,1))

// map:
// mutable.Map[Int, mutable.ListBuffer[(Double, Int)]] = HashMap(
//   1 -> ListBuffer((2.5, 3), (4.5, 1)),
//   2 -> ListBuffer((1.5, 1))
// )
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a tuple, use a grow-able collection like `List` for the `Map` values, and use an empty list as a default value.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val my_var = new mutable.HashMap[Int, List[(Double,Int)]]
               .withDefaultValue(Nil)
```

Now the updates are a bit more verbose, but it all works.

```
my_var += 1->((2.5,3)::my_var(1))
my_var += 1->((4.5,1)::my_var(1))
my_var += 2->((1.5,1)::my_var(2))

my_var //Map(1 -> List((4.5,1), (2.5,3)), 2 -> List((1.5,1)))
```